# Installing scipy on windows 7 x64 python 2.7 32bit

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy

I am having a hell of a time installing scipy. I've tried using anaconda, and I've tried compiling from source only to find there is no support for python 2.7 due to some mingW or Fortran issue or something like that.

Is there any method to this madness?

What's the easiest way to proceed?

All I want to do is use a few functions from the scipy.stats.t

Thanks

edit:
I ultimately want to run in cygwin python myscript.py > output.txt < data.txt
I've gotten it to work in powershell, but powershell has no input/output redirection... LOL such a pain. Any tips in the comments would be appreciated. I have a feeling I'm doing it the wrong way.

Comment: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy

Answer (score 0):

Try installing binaries from [this site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).

Comment: When I go to install the file, it can't find the python installed on my machine. Is this not compatible with cygwin? I need cygwin because DOS doesn't support > and < output redirection. Maybe my whole project is in ruins. How can I get scipy going the easiest way possible? virtual box ubuntu? I guess I'll try that. Sooooo frustrated at scipy after hearing great things about it.

Comment: @SwimBikeRun Cygwin, huh? I have no experience with Python in that environment. Why do you need > % < ? Seems like you could just pass the filenames in as args and use open() to read and write files. You could use ubuntu.